# Why am I unable to access this response.data array in ReactJS/Axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to access the "players" array coming from this API i've called in axios, the return looks like this when I am printing response.data:

[image]

Now, I thought it would be easy to access it, so I tried(without success):

```
response.data.players (print out all players)
response.data.players[0] (print out first player)
response.data[0] (maybe get the array?)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide more information, do you get an error - if so, whats the error?

Comment: When trying to console.log some of these: "TypeError: response.data[0] is undefined"

Comment: did you try response.players?

Comment: There's no `data` property in your screenshot. There **is** a `response` property in your screenshot. So it's likely that you need a `response` property in your access expression, probably `theVariableYouLogged.response.players` (which is an array). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json, which this is a duplicate of (I misvoted earlier).

Comment: Hi, I'm using response.data because it returns the body of what we are calling (https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that `response.data` (based on the screenshot you've attached for `response.data`) has one more property called `response` inside it, which has `players` array. Maybe try using `response.data.response.players[0]`.

Let me know if that doesn't work so I can make necessary changes to the answer :)

Comment: This was the answer! Was confused why it was providing "response" inside of my data.

Comment: Hi @QuestionableCodingPractices, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks :)